# Eastern star at night 2022 July 10

Tags: star, venus

What is the star in the eastern sky tonight with a moon or planet at the 7 o’clock position?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, as you can imagine, there are a lot of stars in the Eastern sky.  If you're just talking about the bright ones, it might be any of Vega, Deneb, or Altair.  It would probably be useful to use a planetarium program like Stellarium to see what the sky looks like at any given time from any given place on Earth.

Comment: More details would be helpful. There are lots of stars "in the east" with other stars to the 7 o'clock position. :-). For example, at what time did you see this? (Is the time in GMT, UT, or your local time?) Where are you located in the world? Can you narrow the direction more than "eastern half of the sky"? For example, is it due east? Southeast? Something in between? Why do you think the object to the 7 o'clock position is a moon or planet? How far apart are the objects? Are you looking with your eyes, binoculars, telescope?

Comment: From [in-the-sky.org/skymap.php](https://in-the-sky.org/skymap.php) using +25° latitude it seems like it might be [Altair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altair)  ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVxBa.jpg))

Comment: Maybe it is Venus. But it needs place, time zone and time with an accuracy of about an hour to give any reasonable answer